# JavaScript setInterval function not updating Gridviews in <div> elements

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview, refresh, setinterval

I have 2  items where the label I use (for testing at least) refreshes with the last update time.  However, the GridViews inside the  elements only update once.  The data parsed out and wrote out normally in a console app, so I'm not sure what the hiccup is.  The strange part, is that although it **does** load data for the first iteration, but doesn't refresh for new data.

Is it the setInterval function that's not working?  I've tried that, and a recursive setTimeout function that I found, but neither worked.  Both have been included with comments showing attempt 1 and 2.

*EDIT* Attempt 2 works if i do **just** an alert(), but calling the C# method makes it run only once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the page:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="CSS/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ProcessData() //Attempt 1
        {
            <%Process_Data();%>
            setTimeout(ProcessData, 3000);
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            ProcessData()
        }, 3000);

    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">     // Attempt 2
        function ProcessData()
        {
            <%Process_Data();%> 
            setTimeout(ProcessData(), 5000);
        }
        ProcessData();
    </script>


    <div class="Images">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="123"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="123"></asp:Label><br />
    </div>
    <div id="dnrLeft" class="DonorsLeft">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <asp:GridView ID="dnrResultsLeft" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DonorName" HeaderText="" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Club" HeaderText="" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dnrRight" class="DonorsRight">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <asp:GridView ID="dnrResultsRight" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DonorName" HeaderText="" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Club" HeaderText="" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here's the code behind it:

```
namespace DnrBoards
{
    public partial class DonorBoardOsh : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<Donors> dnrs = new List<Donors>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DnrBrdDataContext DR = new DnrBrdDataContext())
            {
                var dnrList = (from d in DR.DonorBoards
                               where (d.SiteLocation == "OSH") && (d.Club != "0 Donations")
                               orderby d.Donation_Type, d.Donation_Sum, d.Donor ascending
                               select new
                               {
                                   _DonorName = d.Donor.ToString(),
                                   _Club = d.Club
                               }).ToList();
                foreach (var item in dnrList)
                {
                    dnrs.Add(new Donors(item._DonorName, item._Club));
                }
            }
            Label2.Text = "Last data pull at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }       

        protected void Process_Data()
        {
            List<Donors> dlLeft = new List<Donors>();
            List<Donors> dlRight = new List<Donors>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 43; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    dlLeft.Add(dnrs[0]);
                    dnrs.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 43; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    dlRight.Add(dnrs[0]);
                    dnrs.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            dnrResultsLeft.GridLines = GridLines.None;
            dnrResultsLeft.DataSource = dlLeft;
            dnrResultsLeft.DataBind();

            dnrResultsRight.GridLines = GridLines.None;
            dnrResultsRight.DataSource = dlRight;
            dnrResultsRight.DataBind();

            dlLeft.Clear();
            dlRight.Clear();
            Label1.Text = "Last Refresh: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load will run with every callback update, so dnrs will always be updated with new data from the database on every tick, even if you remove it in the previous one.

The `RemoveAt(i)` logic is strange. `RemoveAt()` removes an item from the list at the position specified, but you're increasing the position each iteration. Simultaneously the array is getting smaller each iteration (because you're removing an item), so will start failing when you get halfway through the list. If you're meaning to take the first item each time from the list, you should `add( dnrs[0])` and `RemoveAt(0)`. This will add the first item from the list, then remove it from dnrs, meaning at the next iteration the next item will now be at index 0.

Comment: Even with the timer being or triggered from inside the update panel?  I've tested both with the same result. Would you be able to provide a better option for how to process it?

The RemoveAt(0) was definitely a helpful suggestion, I missed that part.